# I can't read the values from json_decode() array

Tags: json, stringify

I try to pass some students data through json in wordpress. The data is taken from csv file and it has  a header line and 4 lines of values. I send data to php using
`JSON.stringify(inp)`.
The data is sent without any problem and I decode it using `json_decode`: `$csvdata=json_decode(str_replace("\\","",$_POST['body2']));`
-- I use `str_replace()` because without it the data is not read properly -- `$csvdata` is ok. I send it back to my page using `wp_send_json($csvdata);` and I can see my data in console. However when I try to get the values of `$csvdata`, whatever I try, I get a result of `3 null, null, null data`.

```
$i=0;
foreach($csvdata as $value) {
    $out[$i]=$value->student;
    $i++;
  }
```

and
`wp_send_json($out);`
It should get the values of my data of 'student' field. I tried almost everything with no result. Every time `$out` returns null, null, null

I tried also `$json_decode($_POST['body2'],true)` to read data as an array without any luck. Also tried `html_entity_decode()` or `str_replace()` with many combinations and always no result

Any advices???

[edit] I tried to manually recreate my csvdata like this:

```
$data2 =  json_decode('[{"student":"1","a1":"0"},{"student":"2","a1":"2"},{"student":"3","a1":"0"},{"student":"4","a1":"3"}]');//works
$a=0;
foreach($data2 as $value) {
    $out1[$a]=$value->student;
    $a++;`
 }
    wp_send_json($out1);
```

Now values are read properly. I  notice that on the first place when I wp_send_json($csvdata) in console log there are extra ... (there dots) at the end of each line, which may cause the problem, but I cannot figure out how to solve it...

`{student: 1, a1: 0, a2: 0, a3: 0, a4: 0, …}`

[My data sent to php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssXEo.jpg)

[console result of $csvdata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc5YI.jpg)

Comment: `foreach ($csvdata->data as $value) { ... }`

Comment: Show us some code and [a way to reproduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (a copy of the received JSON in example)

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of attempts I found that the error was because through JSON I was passing metadata together with my data. So I needed to replace JSON.stringify(inp) with JSON.stringify(inp.data)  and everything worked.